# Evaluating $\int x^{15} \cos x^8 \, dx$

Tags: calculus

> $$\int x^{15}\cos x^8 \, dx$$

what I am thinking is using by-parts and let

u = $\cos x^8$

u' = $-8x^7\sin x^8$

v' = $x^{15}$

v = $\left(\frac {x^{16}}{16}\right)$

and then got $\left(\frac {x^{16}}{16}\right)$$\cos x^8$ + $\int 8x^7 \sin x^8 \left(\frac {x^{16}}{16}\right)$ and then I used by-parts again ...
I was trying to make $\int x^{15}\cos x^8 dx$ appear again on the left and right side, but the power of x is increasing. Does it make sense? Or I was wrong at the beginning?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not wrong, it's just not very useful. Rather, considering that the goal is to lower the power of $x$ in front of the cosine, try considering

$$u = x^8, \quad\quad dv = x^7 \cos x^8$$

This leads to an integral of the form

$$\int x^7 \sin x^8\, dx$$

which is tractable.

---

Alternatively, start with the substitution $u = x^8$.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the general problem of $$I_n=\int x^{2n-1}\cos(x^n)\,dx=\int x^nx^{n-1}\cos(x^n)\,dx$$ as suggested in answers and comments, change variable $x^n=t$, $n x^{n-1}dx=dt$ which make $$I_n=\frac 1n\int t\cos(t) \,dt$$ One integration by parts will lead to $$I_n=\frac 1n \big(t \sin (t)+\cos (t)\big)=\frac 1n \big(x^n \sin (x^n)+\cos (x^n)\big)$$

Answer (score 0):

Another easier way could be to use $$x^{16} = t$$ then $$16x^{15}dx = dt$$.
This leads to the $$\frac{1}{16}\int Cos\ t^{1/2}\ dt$$. You can again do substitution if you want as $$ t = u^{2}$$ and apply the chain rule.